# Fourier Transform on a Sound

Tags: fourier-analysis

I don't really know much above Fourier Transform , or how it's used in Mathematica but I want to know how I can find out, out of which Sin-waves a (static) sound is made of.

So for example I take "G" played by a Violin

```
Sound[SoundNote["G", 1, "Violin"]]
```

Because this isn't a pure tone, I want to know, which frequencies are present in which "strength".

My Questions:

How do I get this information?

How do I plot that? (I think it's called "Frequency-Domain")

How do I plot all the involved frequencies together?

I know, this may be simple for some people, but I have neither much know-how in Mathematica, nor do I know how to use Fourier Transform at all.

Hope you can help me, nxt191 aka Marc

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately I don't think that Mathematica really knows anything about the frequency content of `SoundNote` objects.  They are not audio files (recorded in the time domain), but more like MIDI objects.  (In fact I think they're 'sonified' by sending them *as* MIDI events to the OS.)

You *can*, however, do a fourier transform on an audio file.  Either import your own with `Import`, or use one of the example sounds:

```
sound = ExampleData[{"Sound", "ViolinScale"}]
```

We can extract the list of samples from the single `SampledSoundList` inside this `Sound` object:

```
samples = sound[[1, 1, 1]];
```

We can also extract the sample rate:

```
sampleRate = sound[[1, 2]];
```

From here we can compute the FFT and plot:

```
fft = Fourier[samples];
ListLogPlot[Abs[fft]^2, PlotRange -> All, 
 DataRange -> {0, (1 - 1/Length[samples]) sampleRate}]
```

There is a lot of other analysis you can do, but that should get you started.

Comment: It's true that there is no way to get `SampledSoundList` directly from MIDI, but [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96919/how-can-i-convert-a-sound-created-with-soundnote-to-a-list-of-samples) is a workaround.

Comment: Five years later, this question has some activity, and I think it's worth noting that in the current version of Mathematica, `AudioData` does the trick: `AudioData[Sound[SoundNote["G", 1, "Violin"]]]` gives two lists of amplitudes (one for each audio channel). :)

Answer (score 4):

This is easy to do now with *Mathematica's* `Audio` support introduced in v11.0 in 2016 - though note `Spectrogram` was available in 2012 v9.0:

```
au = Audio[Sound[SoundNote["G", 1, "Violin"]]];
Spectrogram[au]

(* ... or if you want an array ... *)
spectrogramData = SpectrogramArray[au];
```

[image: spectrogram]

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the Periodogram function:

```
sound = ExampleData[{"Sound", "ViolinScale"}];
Periodogram[sound,
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> None,
 BaseStyle -> {14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontColor -> Black},
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 14], 
 FrameLabel -> {"Freq (Hz)", "dB"}]
```

[image: Periodogram Plot]